# PHP printf() digit padding with a negative number

Tags: php, printf

When I enter a printf() with a negative parameter for a integer placeholder with a zero padding. The zero padding isn't applied.

```
php > printf('%02d', -6);
-6
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is it a bug?

Comment: what 02 means, is fill with '0' up to length '2', so try this instead

`printf('%s%02d', ( $x < 0 ) ? '-' : '', abs( $x ) );`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per docs:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

paddings is applied on the whole string:

> An optional padding specifier that says what character will be used for padding the results to the right **string size**. This may be a space character or a 0 (zero character). The default is to pad with spaces. An alternate padding character can be specified by prefixing it with a single quote ('). See the examples below.

(emphasis mine).

You may want to use the sign specifier if that is acceptable, e.g.:

```
php > printf('%+03d', -6);
-06
php > printf('%+03d', 6);
+06
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically it's correct because you're specifying 2 digits and the minus sign accounts for one of those.  If you use

```
printf('%03d', -6);
```

you'll get -06.

Answer (score 1):

The "-" counts as a character, so you need to use %03d .

I don't believe this is a bug as 0 padding is often used when working with fields that have a set length, as in characters, so if %02d produced a number with 3 characters the sky might fall.